# Why can i not compile this code and im getting Segmentation fault: 11 in C code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm very new to coding, can someone please help, Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var1 = 5;
    char var2 = 'a';
    int *ptrl = &var1;
    char *ptr2;
    *ptr2= "b";
    print ("var1 tem o mesmo %p e ovalor %d\n", ptr1, *ptr1);
    print ("var1 tem o mesmo %p e ovalor %d\n", ptr2, *ptr2);

}
```

Comment: You can compile this code because you are getting Segmentation fault unless you are using buggy compiler and the compiler is emitting Segmentation fault.

Comment: `ptr2` is pointing to nowhere and you are attempting to assign a value to it!

Comment: Moreover, your code has other errors which most likely were caused by copy and paste. For instance, instead of `print` it should be `printf` and `int *ptrl` should be `int *ptr1`.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
    *ptr2= "b";
```

invokes *undefined behavior* because it uses the (indeterminate) value of `ptr2`, which is uninitialized non-static local variable.

It should be

```
    ptr2 = "b";
```

To set the value of `ptr2` itself instead of what is pointed at by `ptr2`.

Also you should cast pointers for being printed via `%p` to `void*` because the specification requires `void*`.

One more point is that you should use `const char*` for pointers for assigning string literals because modifying string literals is prohivited.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int var1 = 5;
    char var2 = 'a';
    int *ptr1 = &var1;
    const char *ptr2;
    ptr2= "b";
    printf ("var1 tem o mesmo %p e ovalor %d\n", (void*)ptr1, *ptr1);
    printf ("var1 tem o mesmo %p e ovalor %d\n", (void*)ptr2, *ptr2);

}
```

Comment: Thank you MikeCAT, I have one more question could you quickly explain why  ptr2= "b"; has to be in betwin ".

Comment: @MikeCAT My guess is that OP is trying to modify the value of `var2` via `ptr2` pointer in order to see the value of `var2` changing after the assignment in `ptr2= "b";`, which in case my argument is correct, then the assignment should be `ptr2='b';`

Comment: @CRM No, it should be `ptr2=&var2; *ptr2='b';` in that case.

Comment: @MikeCAT Exactly. That is my suspicion about what OP wanted to do originally.